# Invalid hash while implementing PayU integration

Tags: php, android, payment-gateway, payu

When I am trying to integrate the PayU integration. Whatever changes I do I am getting invalid hash. I think I am doing something minor mistake.

For generating the hash I have written in PHP though currently, all data is static I have matched all are same only.

In the following php example I am using `payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash` key in android

Here is my code:

```
paymentIntegration("741852963", "1.0", "SmartAuto", "Piyush", "piyush.sahay@mail.com", "330122983a2492fe6ff18ad2fcccc6a78ed499f988a6b06b226ff4f27b9b390356f18c297282105b2dbb70166bfd0c2332dfa4e55a784543658bd67330f98b39", "XXXXX:XXXXX@XXXXX.com");

private void paymentIntegration(String txnId, String amount, String productName, String userName, String userEmail, String hash1, String userCredentials) {
        HashMap<String, Object> additionalParams = new HashMap<>();
        additionalParams.put(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_UDF1, "udf1");
        additionalParams.put(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_UDF2, "udf2");
        additionalParams.put(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_UDF3, "udf3");
        additionalParams.put(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_UDF4, "udf4");
        additionalParams.put(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_UDF5, "udf5");



        PayUPaymentParams.Builder builder = new PayUPaymentParams.Builder();
        builder.setAmount(amount)
            .setIsProduction(true)
            .setProductInfo(productName)
            .setKey(MERCHANT_KEY)
            .setPhone("XXXXXXXX")
            .setTransactionId(txnId)
            .setFirstName(userName)
            .setEmail(userEmail)
            .setSurl("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success")
            .setFurl("https://payu.herokuapp.com/failure")
            .setUserCredential(userCredentials)
            .setAdditionalParams(additionalParams);

        PayUPaymentParams payUPaymentParams = builder.build();

        PayUCheckoutPro.open(
                this,
                payUPaymentParams,
                new PayUCheckoutProListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentSuccess(Object response) {
                        //Cast response object to HashMap
                        HashMap<String,Object> result = (HashMap<String, Object>) response;
                        String payuResponse = (String)result.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_PAYU_RESPONSE);
                        String merchantResponse = (String) result.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_MERCHANT_RESPONSE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentFailure(Object response) {
                        //Cast response object to HashMap
                        HashMap<String,Object> result = (HashMap<String, Object>) response;
                        String payuResponse = (String)result.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_PAYU_RESPONSE);
                        String merchantResponse = (String) result.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_MERCHANT_RESPONSE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentCancel(boolean isTxnInitiated) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
                        String errorMessage = errorResponse.getErrorMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setWebViewProperties(@Nullable WebView webView, @Nullable Object o) {
                        //For setting webview properties, if any. Check Customized Integration section for more details on this
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void generateHash(HashMap<String, String> valueMap, PayUHashGenerationListener hashGenerationListener) {
                        String hashName = valueMap.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_HASH_NAME);
                        String hashData = valueMap.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_HASH_STRING);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(hashName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(hashData)) {
                            //Do not generate hash from local, it needs to be calculated from server side only. Here, hashString contains hash created from your server side.
                            String hash = hash1;
                            HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                            dataMap.put(hashName, hash);
                            hashGenerationListener.onHashGenerated(dataMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


    }
```

Here is my PHP Code for a hash generation:

```
$output=getHashes("741852963", "1.0", "SmartAuto", "Piyush", "piyush.sahay@gmail.com", "XXXXX:XXXXX@XXXXX.com","udf1","udf2","udf3","udf4","udf5","","" );

function getHashes($txnid, $amount, $productinfo, $firstname, $email, $user_credentials, $udf1, $udf2, $udf3, $udf4, $udf5,$offerKey,$cardBin)
{
      // $firstname, $email can be "", i.e empty string if needed. Same should be sent to PayU server (in request params) also.
      $key = 'XXXXX';
      $salt = 'XXXXXX';

      $payhash_str = $key . '|' . checkNull($txnid) . '|' .checkNull($amount)  . '|' .checkNull($productinfo)  . '|' . checkNull($firstname) . '|' . checkNull($email) . '|' . checkNull($udf1) . '|' . checkNull($udf2) . '|' . checkNull($udf3) . '|' . checkNull($udf4) . '|' . checkNull($udf5) . '||||||' . $salt;
      $paymentHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $payhash_str));
      $arr['payment_hash'] = $paymentHash;

      $cmnNameMerchantCodes = 'get_merchant_ibibo_codes';
      $merchantCodesHash_str = $key . '|' . $cmnNameMerchantCodes . '|default|' . $salt ;
      $merchantCodesHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $merchantCodesHash_str));
      $arr['get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash'] = $merchantCodesHash;

      $cmnMobileSdk = 'vas_for_mobile_sdk';
      $mobileSdk_str = $key . '|' . $cmnMobileSdk . '|default|' . $salt;
      $mobileSdk = strtolower(hash('sha512', $mobileSdk_str));
      $arr['vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $mobileSdk;

      $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk1 = 'payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk';
      $detailsForMobileSdk_str1 = $key  . '|' . $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk1 . '|default|' . $salt ;
      $detailsForMobileSdk1 = strtolower(hash('sha512', $detailsForMobileSdk_str1));
      $arr['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $detailsForMobileSdk1;

      //used for verifying payment(optional)  
      $cmnVerifyPayment = 'verify_payment';
      $verifyPayment_str = $key . '|' . $cmnVerifyPayment . '|'.$txnid .'|' . $salt;
      $verifyPayment = strtolower(hash('sha512', $verifyPayment_str));
      $arr['verify_payment_hash'] = $verifyPayment;

      if($user_credentials != NULL && $user_credentials != '')
      {
            $cmnNameDeleteCard = 'delete_user_card';
            $deleteHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameDeleteCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $deleteHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $deleteHash_str));
            $arr['delete_user_card_hash'] = $deleteHash;

            $cmnNameGetUserCard = 'get_user_cards';
            $getUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameGetUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $getUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $getUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['get_user_cards_hash'] = $getUserCardHash;

            $cmnNameEditUserCard = 'edit_user_card';
            $editUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameEditUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $editUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $editUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['edit_user_card_hash'] = $editUserCardHash;

            $cmnNameSaveUserCard = 'save_user_card';
            $saveUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameSaveUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $saveUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $saveUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['save_user_card_hash'] = $saveUserCardHash;

            $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk = 'payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk';
            $detailsForMobileSdk_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $detailsForMobileSdk = strtolower(hash('sha512', $detailsForMobileSdk_str));
            $arr['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $detailsForMobileSdk;
      }


      // if($udf3!=NULL &amp;&amp; !empty($udf3)){
            $cmnSend_Sms='send_sms';
            $sendsms_str=$key . '|' . $cmnSend_Sms . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $salt;
            $send_sms = strtolower(hash('sha512',$sendsms_str));
            $arr['send_sms_hash']=$send_sms;
      // }


      if ($offerKey!=NULL && !empty($offerKey)) {
                  $cmnCheckOfferStatus = 'check_offer_status';
                        $checkOfferStatus_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnCheckOfferStatus . '|' . $offerKey . '|' . $salt ;
                  $checkOfferStatus = strtolower(hash('sha512', $checkOfferStatus_str));
                  $arr['check_offer_status_hash']=$checkOfferStatus;
            }


            if ($cardBin!=NULL && !empty($cardBin)) {
                  $cmnCheckIsDomestic = 'check_isDomestic';
                        $checkIsDomestic_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnCheckIsDomestic . '|' . $cardBin . '|' . $salt ;
                  $checkIsDomestic = strtolower(hash('sha512', $checkIsDomestic_str));
                  $arr['check_isDomestic_hash']=$checkIsDomestic;
            }



    return $arr;
}

function checkNull($value) {
            if ($value == null) {
                  return '';
            } else {
                  return $value;
            }
      }




echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Hello @Piyush did you fixed this issue ? coz I'm also looking for the same issue.
Don't know why Payu made the implementation this hard without any reference?

Please share any reference if you have any.